# How to pass in an event object to an onchange handler in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, events

I have a number of inputs with onChange handlers in one of my React components, that I am attempting to refactor to use a single method instead of one method per input. My new method I am using is

```
    updatePropertyFromInput = <T, K extends keyof T, V extends T[K]>(targetObject:T, key: K, value: V) => {
    targetObject[key] = value;
}

updateTour = <K extends keyof Tour>(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>, key: K) => {
    let updatedSelectedTourSpec = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.props.SelectedTourSpec)) as TourSpec;
    let updatedTour = updatedSelectedTourSpec.tours.filter((t) => t.tourCode === this.props.Tour.tourCode)[0];

    this.updatePropertyFromInput(updatedTour, key, event.target.value);
}
```

To do this I need to be able to pass in the event to the method from the onChange property. I previously did this like so

```
<input type="number" value={this.props.Tour.flightDays} onChange={this.handleFlightDaysChange} />
```

Which passed in the event automatically. Now that I have 2 arguments I need to pass in the event explicitly like

```
<input type="number" value={this.props.Tour.flightDays} onChange={() => this.updateTour{[event], "flightDays"} />
```

I cannot figure out how to reference the event at `[event]`. When I try to pass in `this` it refers to the React component itself.

How do I reference the event to pass in as an argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply get the event from onChange and pass it further, like this:

```
...onChange={(event) => this.updateTour(event, "flightDays")} />
```

Bear in mind I fixed some incorrect brackets as well.

Answer (score 0):

Event is the default parameter passed to all onChange functions in JS. You've changed the onChange function from directly calling your function to calling an arrow function, and while your function took event as a parameter, the arrow function does not. You need to add something to represent event in the arrow function, like so:

```
<input type="number" value={...} onChange={(event) => this.updateTour(event, "flightDays")} />
```

Because event is the only default parameter of the onChange function, you can replace `event` with whatever you like, but most go with `e` or `event`.